# Youtubeapi illegalstateexception player has been released

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using YoutubeAPI on my app but I am getting `illegalstateexception` of the following code.It says `player has been released`. How do I overcome this problem

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

            if (video_player != null ){

                video_player.seekToMillis(pausedDuration);

        }
        // <-- this will cause re-buffer.
        super.onResume();
    }
```

**edit 1**
initialization of player

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {

            player.cueVideo(video_URL);
            video_player=player;
            prev_cat=cat_id;

        }
    }
```

Also,
I am unable to watch the video of full screen

full-screen code

```
12-16 15:02:38.859: D/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(22422): apps.youtube.core.player.Director.a:473 VideoStage: NEW
12-16 15:02:38.969: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(22422): apps.youtube.core.player.Director.F:521 Media progress reported outside media playback
12-16 15:02:38.979: D/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(22422): apps.youtube.core.player.sequencer.a.<init>:41 SequencerStage: New o
12-16 15:02:38.979: D/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(22422): apps.youtube.core.player.sequencer.a.a:46 SequencerStage: NEW
12-16 15:02:38.989: D/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(22422): apps.youtube.core.player.Director.a:627 PlaybackState reset by init
12-16 15:02:39.019: D/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(22422): apps.youtube.core.player.sequencer.a.a:46 SequencerStage: VIDEO_LOADING
```

Comment: can you post your rest of the code(how you are loading the video)?

Comment: did you try the sample application? and try player.loadVideo(id);?

Comment: no what i am saying is replace  player.cueVideo(video_URL); line with  player.loadVideo(video_URL); and did you see the youtube api sample appication for android?

Comment: sample code says cue, I have tried load() also... but its failing, any settings to be added in manifest ?

Comment: i guess it is heard to guess from this code. i need to see the full code if possible?

Comment: I m also facing the same problem ................  Media progress reported outside media playback. Is there any solution for this... pls   suggest

Comment: @akki please check the solution I have founded

Comment: @onkar: A little late to the party but I hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/33436981/5384453

Comment: I solve question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332765/android-youtube-player-has-been-released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcome this issue by making videoPlayer null in `onDestroy` of Activity.