# Android : youtube player has been released

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm getting this error `Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
This YouTubePlayer has been released` , but `release()` wasn't called explicitly.Here is the piece of code where crash occurs :

```
if(youtubePlayer != null){
 time = youtubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();//exception may occur
}
```

is it possible to check that `youtubePlayer` was `released`? Any callback ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post how you are creating instance of youtubePlayer ?
Also does you Activity implement any Listeners  ?

Comment: Are you using  YouTubePlayerFragment or YouTubePlayerView or YouTubeStandalonePlayer

Comment: @Kakarot, Hi , I'm using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` - for yt view and `YouTubePlayer` interface for player. Here is the init code : `youTubeView.initialize(YouTubeUtils.DEVELOPER_KEY,
     mPlayerInitializedListener);` and I get instance of player in this callback : `public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
    final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {...}`.Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Most of the code in the Youtube SDK is obfuscated which makes it really hard to debug. And the fact that **there isn't any direct method to check if the YoutubePlayer has been released or not** doesn't help either.

Having said that I think **making YoutubePlayer null (in onStop()) seems more of a *hack* than a proper solution** to me. You should release the YoutubePlayer in onDestroy() and don't manually assign it as null anywhere. One simple approach to check if the YoutubePlayer has been released  or not is **put your calls (like youtubePlayer.loadVideo(), cueVideo(), getCurrentTimeMillis() etc.) in a try catch block and catch the IllegalStateException exception.**

According to the [Youtube SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason) on errors:

> public static final YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason
>   UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION
>
> Playback has been canceled and the player has been released due to an
>   unexpected disconnection from the YouTube API service. Any further
>   calls to this player instance will result in errors, a new player
>   instance must be created to re-enable playback.

**So to create a new instance of the YoutubePlayer just call the initialize() method in the catch block.**

Example:

```
public void setVideoId(final String videoId) {
    if (videoId != null && !videoId.equals(this.videoId)) {
        this.videoId = videoId;
        if (youtubePlayer != null) {
            try {
                youtubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                initialize(API_KEY, this);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {   
    if (youtubePlayer != null) {
        youtubePlayer.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by making videoPlayer null in `onDestroy` of Activity.

**Edit:**

Tried in `onStop` and it works fine. 

@MickeyTin, Thanks..

Comment: In my case player can be released before `onDestroy`

Answer (score 0):

The type of variable returned by `youtubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();` is a `int`.
This should work:

```
if(youtubePlayer != null){
 int millis = youtubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();//exception may occur
}
```

Comment: Java is a Strongly Typed Language

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to get rid of this exception. In my case it was thrown on onSaveInstanceState where I tried to save current player position using the same piece of code:

```
if(youtubePlayer != null){ time = youtubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis(); }
```

and upon successfull player initialization in onInitializationSuccess I continued playing video using the **time** value assigned in onCreate from Bundle.

But it turned out that such approach is unnecessary. To avoid the exception throw I just added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` attribute to my player activity in manifest. This makes the system handle orientation changes by itself, and adding **time** parameter to cueing the video becomes redundant. This is what checking the **wasRestored** flag is made for in onInitializationSuccess.

Here's the changes summary:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

VideoPlayerActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        this.mPlayer = player;
        if (!wasRestored) {
            mPlayer.loadVideo(mVideoId);
        }
    }
```