# Youtube Player has been released when activity created on device rotate

Tags: android, youtube, android-studio, youtube-api

YouTube player has been released when devices rotate and activity recreated. Then play video. Shows YouTube player has released. I don't know where it released. I have already set it to Null onDestroy Method.

```
`mPlayer.loadVideo(videoId);`
```

> //pointing YouTube Player released

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: video play first time perfectly...when you rotate the device...Activity re Created...and then if you want to play video,,,error is youtube player has been released....where it has released...and how fix it?

Comment: @AwaisAli: A little late to the party but I hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/33436981/5384453

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to save the current playing time by YouTubePlayer `getCurrentTimeMillis()` in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state)` when screen rotation gets triggered, and get the time back from `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state)`.

Sample code would be:

```
static final String CURRENT_PLAY_TIME = "current_play_time";
int current_time;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    state.putInt(CURRENT_PLAY_TIME, youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    current_time = state.getInt(CURRENT_PLAY_TIME);
}
```

And after restoring the current playing time let YouTubePlayer load video with it.

```
youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID, current_time);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A posible solution is make your app vertical or horizontal permanent

For doing this write within your manifest:

```
<android:screenOrientation="portrait"> //vertical
<android:screenOrientation="landscape"> //horizontal
```

Comment: in one orientation its working perfectly...but need to play after rotate the device either in portrait or landscape...have idea?

Comment: you can choice landscape or portrait for each activity, but actually you want use the 2 and the problem is when you change between them, may be you need another layout, once for protrait and another for landscape

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> I have found my Excelent solution..all going good with youtube player
> ```

```
@Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                if (mPlayer != null)
                    //Set YouTube Player here;
            }
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                if (mPlayer != null)
                  //Set YouTube Player here;
            }
        }
```